# Laravel Eloquent - auto-numbering on has many relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm very much a beginner when it comes to database relationships hence what I suspect is a basic question! I have two database tables as follows:

**Projects**

- id
- company_id
- name
- etc...

**rfis**

- id
- project_id (foreign key is id on the Projects table above)
- Number (this is the column I need help with - more below)
- question

The relationships at the Model level for these tables are as follows:

**Project**

```
public function rfi()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rfi'); 
}
```

**RFI**

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

**What I'm trying to achieve**
In the RFI table I need a system generated number or essentially a count of RFI's. Where I'm finding the difficulty is that I need the RFI number/count to start again for each project. To clarify, please see the RFI table below which I have manually created with the the 'number' how I would like it displayed (notice it resets for each new project and the count starts from there).

[image]

Any assistance would be much appreciated!
Todd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `number` field depends on the number of `project_id` in the RFI table. It is exactly the number of rows with `project_id` plus one.

So when you want to insert a new row, you calculate `number` based on project_id and assign it.

```
RFI::create([
    'project_id' => $project_id,
    'number' => RFI::where('project_id', $project_id)->count() + 1,
    ...
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want to set the value of the "number" field to "1" if it's a new project and "increment" if it's an existing project. And you want to automate this without checking for it every time you save a new row for "RFI" table.

What you need is a mutator. It's basically a method that you will write inside the desired Model class and there you will write your own logic for saving data. Laravel will run that function automatically every time you save something. [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators) you will learn more about mutators.

Use this method inside the "RFI" model class.

```
public function setNumberAttribute($value)
{
    if(this is new project)
        $this->attributes['number'] = 1;
    else
        $this->attributes['number']++;
}
```

Bonus topic: while talking about mutators, there's also another type of method called accessor. It does the same thing as mutators do, but just the opposite. Mutators get called while saving data, accessors get called while fetching data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - I'll definitely learn about mutators. Thanks for the quick reply.